# 400 Bad Request When Authenticating for MS Graph

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I have a local bot working when I use the emulator. The bot sends an OAuth card to the user, the user gets a verification code and can use that to successfully sign in. I published my bot to Azure and noticed that when I press the login button, it takes me to [here](https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/login/6614916a-fcc3-4f9d-294c-fd8ad1170bb5_08a48bd3-4ba1-a001-6187?redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftoken.botframework.com%2fapi%2foauth%2fPostSignInCallback%3fsignin%3d921d46120f051810070b1f4dd8999313c570f1ad15%26code_challenge%3d) which just says "Bad Request." No other error messages display so I don't know what the problem is.

I sign the user in using:

```
// in constructor
oauthPrompt = new OAuthPrompt("sign-in", { connectionName: "mg-graph", title: "Login" });

dialogs.add(oauthPrompt);`

dialogs.add(
    new WaterfallDialog(
        "wf-sign-in",
        [
            async step => {
                return await step.prompt("sign-in", "Login");
            },
            async step => {
                console.log(step.result.token);
                return step.endDialog();
            }
        ].map(x => x.bind(this))
    )
);

// in onTurn()
await dialogContext.beginDialog("wf-sign-in");
```

Comment: Which channel(s) are you using and what kind OAuth provider is this connecting through (AAD, Google, etc)?

Comment: I'm using the web channel, authenticating using Azure AD v2. I also used the web chat SDK with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use) code snippet.

Comment: Can you double check that you are still receiving a 'bad request' message? I was testing this yesterday evening and I was also receiving the message on a bot that OAuth previously had worked fine. However, now both mine and your code is working fine for me.

Comment: I received the same response. 400 Bad Request. I also tested the production environment in the bot emulator and I also receive a 400 bad request. Development works fine however.

Comment: When I make my appID and password the same in the bot file for "development" and "production", production now works in the bot emulator but not in the web chat channel online.

Comment: I noticed I have 2 different app IDs and passwords. One for dev and one for production. Are they supposed to be the same? I never intended to have a "dev" login and a "production" login.

Comment: You can run "development" purely local without the Id or pw. But, if you test external services (e.g. Teams), then you need to have those entered. You would also connect via ngrok for tunneling. Id/pw come from the Azure Bot Service bot you have hosted on Azure. For "production", you need both. It should also be the values of the ABS bot. You deploy your local "production" bot with these values in place so it can run in Azure. Do they have to be the same? No. One has no bearing on the other. However, any local settings should match the ABS bot that has OAuth connection you are using.